# Using atan2 to find angle between two vectors

Tags: math, vector, geometry

I understand that:

`atan2(vector.y, vector.x)` = the angle between the **vector and the X axis**.

But I wanted to know how to get the angle between **two vectors** using atan2. So I came across this solution:

```
atan2(vector1.y - vector2.y, vector1.x - vector2.x)
```

My question is very simple:

Will the two following formulas produce the same number?

- `atan2(vector1.y - vector2.y, vector1.x - vector2.x)`
- `atan2(vector2.y - vector1.y, vector2.x - vector1.x)`

If not: **How do I know what vector comes first in the subtractions?**

Comment: @andand no, `atan2` can be used for 3D vectors : `double angle = atan2(norm(cross_product), dot_product);` and it's even more precise then `acos` version.

Comment: This doesn't take into account angles greater than 180; I'm looking for something that can return a result 0 - 360, not limited to 0 - 180.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Direct way of computing clockwise angle between 2 vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066933/direct-way-of-computing-clockwise-angle-between-2-vectors)

Answer (score 169, accepted):

```
 atan2(vector1.y - vector2.y, vector1.x - vector2.x)
```

is the angle between the *difference vector* (connecting vector2 and vector1) and the x-axis,
which is problably not what you meant.

---

The (directed) angle from vector1 to vector2 can be computed as

```
angle = atan2(vector2.y, vector2.x) - atan2(vector1.y, vector1.x);
```

and you may want to normalize it to the range [0, 2 π):

```
if (angle < 0) { angle += 2 * M_PI; }
```

or to the range (-π, π]:

```
if (angle > M_PI)        { angle -= 2 * M_PI; }
else if (angle <= -M_PI) { angle += 2 * M_PI; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. So what you suggest, is getting the angle between vector2 and the x axis (let's call it angle1), getting the angle between vector1 and the x axis (lets call it angle2), and then subtracting the two. Correct?
If so: What would be the difference between angle1 and angle2? Would angle1 be `x` and angle2 be `-x`? More importantly, how do I choose which angle comes first in the subtraction?

Comment: @user3150201: It depends on what you want, because there are two angles between the vectors. - The above method gives an angle a such that if you turn vector1 counter-clockwise by this angle, then the result is vector2.

Comment: @user3150201: Or do you want the *smaller* of the two possible angles between the vectors, i.e. a result in the range 0 .. Pi ?

Comment: This solution needs 2 calls of `atan2`, which are costly, while this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21486462/5769463 needs only one.

Comment: @ead: That is correct, the difference is measurable but not dramatic. With a simple C program computing the angles between 1,000,000 random vectors I got 97 milliseconds vs 73 milliseconds. That may or many not be relevant in a real-world application.

Answer (score 60):

A robust way to do it is by finding the sine of the angle using the cross product, and the cosine of the angle using the dot product and combining the two with the `Atan2()` function.

In `C#` this is:

```cs
public struct Vector2
{
    public double X, Y;

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the angle between two vectos
    /// </summary>
    public static double GetAngle(Vector2 A, Vector2 B)
    {
        // |A·B| = |A| |B| COS(θ)
        // |A×B| = |A| |B| SIN(θ)

        return Math.Atan2(Cross(A,B), Dot(A,B));
    }

    public double Magnitude { get { return Math.Sqrt(Dot(this,this)); } }

    public static double Dot(Vector2 A, Vector2 B)
    {
        return A.X*B.X+A.Y*B.Y;
    }
    public static double Cross(Vector2 A, Vector2 B)
    {
        return A.X*B.Y-A.Y*B.X;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Vector2 A=new Vector2() { X=5.45, Y=1.12};
        Vector2 B=new Vector2() { X=-3.86, Y=4.32 };

        double angle=Vector2.GetAngle(A, B) * 180/Math.PI;
        // angle = 120.16850967865749
    }
}
```

See the test case above in GeoGebra.

[image: GeoGebra]

Comment: I added a graphical test case for illustration.

Comment: I am always reluctant to call something *the proper* method, but yes, this is fine. Note that you don't have to divide by `(A.Magnitude*B.Magnitude)` (and therefore don't need to calculate the magnitude at all).

Comment: Yes, I will edit the answer. It is  the proper way in a mathematical way becasue it can works in both 2D and 3D.

Comment: That's a very non-standard definition of cross product.  The more traditional definition of the cross product is given at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product.

Comment: @andand: See (8), (9) in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CrossProduct.html. As far as I know, it *is* often called cross-product of two vectors in the plane.

Comment: Just expand out `[ax,ay,0]×[bx,by,0] = ax*by-ay*bx`. You can always go from 3D to 2D by setting the z as zero.

Comment: @MartinR Right, the definition above is for the determinant, not the cross product... the cross product returns a vector orthogonal to the other two.

Comment: @andand 2D × results in an orhogonal vector `[0,0,ax*by-ay*bx]` and above I have only z component returned in `Cross(A,B)`.

Comment: Here's a javascript version: http://bl.ocks.org/shancarter/1034db3e675f2d3814e6006cf31dbfdc

Comment: Thanks for mentioning GeoGebra, an awesome tool!

Comment: Actually, `A·B = |A| |B| COS(θ)` and `|A×B| = |A| |B| SIN(θ)`, since `A·B` returns a scalar and `A×B` a vector. That means that if you want to get the angle in `[0, pi)` you have to do `Math.Atan2(Math.Abs(Cross(A,B)), Dot(A,B));`

Comment: @ChronoTrigger - I make a distinction between clockwise and counterclockwise rotations based on the order of the operands.

Comment: Note that I read somewhere recently that a bit more robust is not consider only the dot product and use `angle = Math.Acos(Dot(A,B));`

Comment: It is not robust, because the cross product does not exist in higher dimensions (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/720820/553149)).
Unfortunately the standard inner product method (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1267817/angle-between-two-4d-vectors)) only returns up to Pi radians (180°).

Comment: @Elaskanator - what is the meaning of an angle in higher dimensions (beyond 3?) I guess you can always do in the inner product and use `acos(x)` to get this "angle".

Answer (score 26):

I think a better formula was posted here:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/16243-angle-between-two-vectors-in-3d

```
angle = atan2(norm(cross(a,b)), dot(a,b))
```

So this formula works in 2 or 3 dimensions.
For 2 dimensions this formula simplifies to the one stated above.

Comment: That is what @ja72 suggested in his/her answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21486462/1187415.

Comment: took me a while to realize that norm is not normalize, but it is a vector length

Comment: This formula discards sign of y component, since `norm(cross(a,b))` will be always positive.

Answer (score 8):

Nobody pointed out that if you have a single vector, and want to find the angle of the vector from the X axis, you can take advantage of the fact that the argument to atan2() is actually the slope of the line, or (delta Y / delta X). So if you know the slope, you can do the following:

given:

A = angle of the vector/line you wish to determine (from the X axis).

m = signed slope of the vector/line.

then:

A = atan2(m, 1)

Very useful!

Comment: Well A = atan2(y,x) gives the same result + deals correctly with small x values: on your solution, your m could be infinite when x is near 0, which is not correctly handled by floats and even double.

Answer (score 2):

If you care about accuracy for small angles, you want to use this:

angle = 2*atan2(|| ||b||a - ||a||b ||, || ||b||a + ||a||b ||)

Where "||" means absolute value, AKA "length of the vector". See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1143354/numerically-stable-method-for-angle-between-3d-vectors/1782769

However, that has the downside that in two dimensions, it loses the sign of the angle.

Answer (score 2):

As a complement to the answer of @martin-r one should note that it is possible to use the sum/difference formula for arcus tangens.

```
angle = atan2(vec2.y, vec2.x) - atan2(vec1.y, vec1.x);
angle = -atan2(vec1.x * vec2.y - vec1.y * vec2.x, dot(vec1, vec2))
        where dot = vec1.x * vec2.x  + vec1.y * vec2.y
```

- **Caveat 1**: make sure the angle remains within -pi ... +pi
- **Caveat 2**: beware when the vectors are getting very similar, you might get extinction in the first argument, leading to numerical inaccuracies

Answer (score 1):

You don't *have* to use atan2 to calculate the angle between two vectors. If you just want the quickest way, you can use `dot(v1, v2)=|v1|*|v2|*cos A`
to get

```
A = Math.acos( dot(v1, v2)/(v1.length()*v2.length()) );
```

Comment: This formula discards the sense of the angle (+ or -, clockwise or counterclockwise).  You can see this because swapping v1 and v2 doesn't change the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
angle(vector.b,vector.a)=pi/2*((1+sgn(xa))*(1-sgn(ya^2))-(1+sgn(xb))*(1-sgn(yb^2)))

+pi/4*((2+sgn(xa))*sgn(ya)-(2+sgn(xb))*sgn(yb))

+sgn(xa*ya)*atan((abs(xa)-abs(ya))/(abs(xa)+abs(ya)))

-sgn(xb*yb)*atan((abs(xb)-abs(yb))/(abs(xb)+abs(yb)))
```

xb,yb and xa,ya are the coordinates of the two vectors

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: You should combine the answers to one. Otherwise people might not really accept the answers

Answer (score 1):

The formula, `angle(vector.b,vector.a)`, that I sent, give results

in the four quadrants and for any coordinates `xa,ya` and `xb,yb`.

For coordinates `xa=ya=0` and **or** `xb=yb=0` is **undefined**.

The angle can be bigger or smaller than `pi`, and can be positive

or negative.

Answer (score 1):

Here a little program in Python that uses the angle between vectors to determine if a point is inside or outside a certain polygon

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
from pprint import pprint

# Plot variables
x_min, x_max = -6, 12
y_min, y_max = -3, 8
tick_interval = 1
FIG_SIZE = (10, 10)
DELTA_ERROR = 0.00001
IN_BOX_COLOR = 'yellow'
OUT_BOX_COLOR = 'black'


def angle_between(v1, v2):
    """ Returns the angle in radians between vectors 'v1' and 'v2'
        The sign of the angle is dependent on the order of v1 and v2
        so acos(norm(dot(v1, v2))) does not work and atan2 has to be used, see:
        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21483999/using-atan2-to-find-angle-between-two-vectors
    """
    arg1 = np.cross(v1, v2)
    arg2 = np.dot(v1, v2)
    angle = np.arctan2(arg1, arg2)
    return angle


def point_inside(point, border):
    """ Returns True if point is inside border polygon and False if not
        Arguments:
        :point: x, y in shapely.geometry.Point type
        :border: [x1 y1, x2 y2, ... , xn yn] in shapely.geomettry.Polygon type
    """    
    assert len(border.exterior.coords) > 2,\
        'number of points in the polygon must be > 2'

    point = np.array(point)
    side1 = np.array(border.exterior.coords[0]) - point
    sum_angles = 0
    for border_point in border.exterior.coords[1:]:
        side2 = np.array(border_point) - point
        angle = angle_between(side1, side2)
        sum_angles += angle
        side1 = side2

    # if wn is 1 then the point is inside
    wn = sum_angles / 2 / np.pi
    if abs(wn - 1) < DELTA_ERROR:
        return True
    else:
        return False


class MainMap():

    @classmethod
    def settings(cls, fig_size):
        # set the plot outline, including axes going through the origin
        cls.fig, cls.ax = plt.subplots(figsize=fig_size)
        cls.ax.set_xlim(-x_min, x_max)
        cls.ax.set_ylim(-y_min, y_max)
        cls.ax.set_aspect(1)
        tick_range_x = np.arange(round(x_min + (10*(x_max - x_min) % tick_interval)/10, 1),
            x_max + 0.1, step=tick_interval)
        tick_range_y = np.arange(round(y_min + (10*(y_max - y_min) % tick_interval)/10, 1), 
            y_max + 0.1, step=tick_interval)
        cls.ax.set_xticks(tick_range_x)
        cls.ax.set_yticks(tick_range_y)
        cls.ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=6)
        cls.ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
        cls.ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
        cls.ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
        cls.ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')

    @classmethod
    def get_ax(cls):
        return cls.ax

    @staticmethod
    def plot():
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.show()


class PlotPointandRectangle(MainMap):

    def __init__(self, start_point, rectangle_polygon, tolerance=0):

        self.current_object = None
        self.currently_dragging = False
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.on_key)
        self.plot_types = ['o', 'o-']
        self.plot_type = 1
        self.rectangle = rectangle_polygon

        # define a point that can be moved around
        self.point = patches.Circle((start_point.x, start_point.y), 0.10,
            alpha=1)
        if point_inside(start_point, self.rectangle):
            _color = IN_BOX_COLOR
        else:
            _color = OUT_BOX_COLOR
        self.point.set_color(_color)
        self.ax.add_patch(self.point)
        self.point.set_picker(tolerance)
        cv_point = self.point.figure.canvas
        cv_point.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self.on_release)
        cv_point.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.on_pick)
        cv_point.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.on_motion)

        self.plot_rectangle()

    def plot_rectangle(self):
        x = [point[0] for point in self.rectangle.exterior.coords]
        y = [point[1] for point in self.rectangle.exterior.coords]
        # y = self.rectangle.y
        self.rectangle_plot, = self.ax.plot(x, y,
            self.plot_types[self.plot_type], color='r', lw=0.4, markersize=2)

    def on_release(self, event):
        self.current_object = None
        self.currently_dragging = False

    def on_pick(self, event):
        self.currently_dragging = True
        self.current_object = event.artist

    def on_motion(self, event):
        if not self.currently_dragging:
            return
        if self.current_object == None:
            return

        point = Point(event.xdata, event.ydata)
        self.current_object.center = point.x, point.y
        if point_inside(point, self.rectangle):
            _color = IN_BOX_COLOR
        else:
            _color = OUT_BOX_COLOR
        self.current_object.set_color(_color)

        self.point.figure.canvas.draw()

    def remove_rectangle_from_plot(self):
        try:
            self.rectangle_plot.remove()
        except ValueError:
            pass

    def on_key(self, event):
        # with 'space' toggle between just points or points connected with
        # lines
        if event.key == ' ':
            self.plot_type = (self.plot_type + 1) % 2
            self.remove_rectangle_from_plot()
            self.plot_rectangle()
            self.point.figure.canvas.draw()


def main(start_point, rectangle):

    MainMap.settings(FIG_SIZE)
    plt_me = PlotPointandRectangle(start_point, rectangle)  #pylint: disable=unused-variable
    MainMap.plot()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        start_point = Point([float(val) for val in sys.argv[1].split()])
    except IndexError:
        start_point= Point(0, 0)

    border_points = [(-2, -2),
                     (1, 1),
                     (3, -1),
                     (3, 3.5),
                     (4, 1),
                     (5, 1),
                     (4, 3.5),
                     (5, 6),
                     (3, 4),
                     (3, 5),
                     (-0.5, 1),
                     (-3, 1),
                     (-1, -0.5),
                    ]               

    border_points_polygon = Polygon(border_points)
    main(start_point, border_points_polygon)
```