# How to get the cursor position relative to ANY form of UIElement

Tags: c#, math, geometry

I'm trying to find the cursor position related to the red line in the image below.

I tried these topics: 
[Using atan2 to find angle between two vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21483999/using-atan2-to-find-angle-between-two-vectors)
And [How to calculate the angle between a line and the horizontal axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586063/how-to-calculate-the-angle-between-a-line-and-the-horizontal-axis) but using
    *Math.Atan2*

But there is a problem, P1 and P2 have not same values if I use these methods.

Is there any method to get any position of any points on a UIElement (e.g. Ellipse) using the red vector such as every point with the same angle (here P1 and P2) has the same value ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and atan2 is perfectly the needed method. We can use cross- and dot-product to achieve result:

```
 bx = redline_end.x - center.x
 by = redline_end.y - center.y
 // here bx=0 and by=75
 px = p1.x - center.x
 py = p1.y - center.y
 angle = atan2(px * by - py * bx, px * bx + py * by)  //and similar for P2
```

Comment: Just tried it out and it looks like it works perfectly ! Just to be sure that I understood it: `redline_end.x` is 0 and `redline_end.Y` is `Height/2` ?

Comment: Not exactly - here `0` and`Height/2` corresponds to coordinate **differences** between end and start of the red line (bx, by), not to coordinates themselves.