# Can camera.lookAt function be calculated from an angle and an axis of rotation, given a target point and the camera forward?

Tags: graphics, three.js, linear-algebra

I am trying to understand three.js's camera.lookAt function, and to implement my own.

I'm using eye = camera position, target = target look at point, and up is always (0, 1, 0). A friend proposed that the obvious way to rotate a camera to look at a point in space would be to get the desired forward by calculating target - eye, and compute the angle between the camera's forward vector (0, 0, -1) and the target forward (using atan2 method described [in these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21483999/using-atan2-to-find-angle-between-two-vectors)), and this is the angle of rotation. I would be able to find the axis of the rotation by computing the crossProduct of the forward vector and the desired forward. I would use a function like [setFromAxisAngle](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Quaternion.setFromAxisAngle) to get the resulting quaternion.

Tried to draw it here:

[image]

Would this work in theory? When testing it against the canonical [lookAt](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/math/Matrix4.js#L304) method, which uses eye, up, and target and does z = (eye - target), x = Cross(up, z), y = Cross(x, z) -- (also, why is it eye - target instead of target - eye?)  -- I see small ( < 0.1 differences).

Answer (score 2):

I personally think the implementation of `three.js`'s `Matri4.lookAt()` method is somewhat confusing. It's also in the wrong class, it should be placed in `Matrix3`. Anyway, a more clear implementation can be found in the `MathGeoLib`, a C++ library for linear algebra and geometry manipulation for computer graphics.

https://github.com/juj/MathGeoLib/blob/ae6dc5e9b1ec83429af3b3ba17a7d61a046d3400/src/Math/float3x3.h#L167-L198
https://github.com/juj/MathGeoLib/blob/ae6dc5e9b1ec83429af3b3ba17a7d61a046d3400/src/Math/float3x3.cpp#L617-L678

A `lookAt()` method should first build an orthonormal linear basis A (`localRight`, `localUp`, `localForward`) for the object's local space. Then it builds an orthonormal linear basis B (`worldRight`, `worldUp`, `targetDirection`) for the desired target orientation. The primary task of `lookAt()` is to map from basis A to B. This is done by multiplying `m1` (basis B) with the inverse of `m2`(basis A). Since this matrix is orthonormal, the inverse is computed by a simple transpose.

```
m1.makeBasis( worldRight, worldUp, targetDirection );
m2.makeBasis( localRight, localUp, localForward );

this.multiplyMatrices( m1, m2.transpose() );
```

`this` references to an instance of a 3x3 matrix class.

I suggest you carefully study the well-documented C++ code in order to understand each single step of the method.

Comment: Thank you, that's a good explanation and example-- I actually feel like I understand the lookAt function and how it is computing an orthonormal basis for the camera, I am mostly wondering why the same thing cannot be achieved by getting the angle and axis of rotation between the default camera forward vector and the desired forward vector (target - eye).