# Matlab - How to perform operations on each row between two matrices?

Tags: matlab, vector, vectorization, angle

I have two matrices each of which contains two vectors (each row is a vector):

```matlab
u = [1 0 0; 2 0 0]
v = [1 1 0; 2 2 0]
```

I want to calculate two angles between the vectors of the corresponding rows in the matrices (angle between `[1 0 0] , [1 1 0]` and angle between `[2 0 0] , [2 2 0]`). In this example, both angles will be 45 degrees. So what I want is a new matrix like this:

```matlab
angles = [45; 45]
```

When I try this:

```matlab
u = [1 0 0; 2 0 0]
v = [1 1 0; 2 2 0]
dp = u(:,1) .* v(:,1) + u(:,2) .* v(:,2) + u(:,3) .* v(:,3);
angles = atan2d(norm(cross(u,v)),dp)
```

The anwser will be:

```matlab
angles = [76.3670 ; 45.8683]
```

and when I try this (change `norm` to `normr`):

```matlab
u = [1 0 0; 2 0 0]
v = [1 1 0; 2 2 0]
dp = u(:,1) .* v(:,1) + u(:,2) .* v(:,2) + u(:,3) .* v(:,3);
angles = atan2d(norm(crossr(u,v)),dp)
```

The anwser will be:

```matlab
angles = [0 0 45.0000 ; 0 0 14.0362]
```

How can I make it calculate the angle between the vectors of each row?

Comment: `norm(cross(u,v))` returns a scalar, not a vector (matrix norm, not two vector norms).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
u=[1 0 0;2 0 0];
v = [1 1 0;2 2 0];
atan2(cross(u,v,2),dot(u,v,2)) % radians
atan2d(cross(u,v,2),dot(u,v,2)) % degrees
```

The `,2` in the [cross](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cross.html) and [dot](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dot.html) functions specifies the dimension to operate, since you are storing each vector in a row.

There a discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21483999/using-atan2-to-find-angle-between-two-vectors), with many other ways to calculate, and you may find one more suitable to your particular case of application.